# Jenkins fail to load groovy class

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am having a groovy class in file : src/utils/versionUtil.groovy
I am trying to load it in my JenkinsFile but I got this error :

```
    java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TEST-web-cyclo-gitflow/workspace/src/utils/versionUtil.groovy
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:317)
.....etc
```

Jenkinsfile

```
node {
    stage('helloWorld') {
        def VersionUtils = load pwd() + '/src/utils/versionUtil.groovy'
    }
}
```

How to load properly a groovy class in jenkinsFile?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use [shared libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) for that:

```
@Library('somelib') import com.mycorp.pipeline.somelib.UsefulClass
```